# Python - issue with strings and .format()

Tags: python, raw-input, string.format

I've just started to learn Python and I'm making a little game to practice what I've learnt. I've encountered a slight problem, though:

## Here's the part that's not working:

```
name = raw_input("Enter Name: ")

print""

print "^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"

start_message = raw_input("Another day on Uranus, {name}!. Shall we go outside or stay within the protection bubble? (Press 'Enter')").format(name=name)
```

## The output:

```
Enter Name: James


^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Another day on Uranus, {name}!. Shall we go outside or stay within the protection bubble? (Press 'Enter')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are formatting the `raw_input` not the string within the `raw_input`. You need to change where your parenthesis is:

```
start_message = raw_input("Another day on Uranus, {name}!. Shall we go outside or stay within the protection bubble? (Press 'Enter')".format(name=name))
```

Notice that I pulled the parenthesis from after the closing `"` to after the `format` and now it's all in `raw_input()`

Output:

```
Enter Name: Andy

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Another day on Uranus, Andy!. Shall we go outside or stay within the protection bubble? (Press 'Enter')
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah you have a parenthesis error.

```
start_message = raw_input("Another day on Uranus, {name}!. Shall we go outside or stay within the protection bubble? (Press 'Enter')").format(name=name)
```

needs to be

```
start_message = raw_input("Another day on Uranus, {name}!. Shall we go outside or stay within the protection bubble? (Press 'Enter')".format(name=name))
```

Comment: Ah Padraic Cunningham got it

Comment: the voting on SO never ceases to amaze, the last answer 5 minutes after the first with the exact same suggestion is the only upvoted

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the string you pass to `raw_input:`

```
 ......(Press 'Enter')".format(name=name)
```

You are trying to format the input you take from `raw_input`.